# 8 bytes skipped while I try to make objects?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class V3 {
public:
    double x, y, z;
    V3(double a, double b, double c) {
        x=a;
        y=b;
        z=c;
        cout << "Addresses are " << &x << " " << &y << " " << &z << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    V3 a(1,1,1), b(2,2,2), c(3,3,3), d(4,4,4);
    cout << sizeof(a) << " " << sizeof(b) << " " << sizeof(c) << " " << sizeof(d) << endl;
}
```

In the code mentioned above, I'm trying to see how C++ stores objects in memory. On running this code, I get the following output -

```
Addresses are 0x7ffc5996b160 0x7ffc5996b168 0x7ffc5996b170
Addresses are 0x7ffc5996b180 0x7ffc5996b188 0x7ffc5996b190
Addresses are 0x7ffc5996b1a0 0x7ffc5996b1a8 0x7ffc5996b1b0
Addresses are 0x7ffc5996b1c0 0x7ffc5996b1c8 0x7ffc5996b1d0
24 24 24 24
```

So for object `b`, I wonder why I did not get `0x7ffc5996b178` as my address. Why is C++ skipping 8 bytes before starting the next object?

Comment: What platform (OS, compiler, version)?  Is optimization turned on or off?

Comment: g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4. No additional flags used while compiling

Comment: Does the second constructor make any difference?  If not, why is it included? (See MCVE — [MCVE].)  Are the assignments necessary?  Does anything change if you use `V3(double a, double b, double c) : x(a), y(b), z(c) { cout << …; }`?  I don't expect there to be a difference.  Did you try printing the addresses of the class objects in `main()`?  Does that throw any light on things?  Ultimately, though, your question is futile — the compiler is allowed to use any layout and alignment it chooses as long as it gives the correct results.

Comment: Just a guess: x86 cache lines are 64 bytes. By aligning this way, the first 2 objects would fit in 1 cache line, and the third would fit in a second cache line. If they were not aligned this way, the third object would be split across 2 cache lines which is bad.

As Jonathan said though, it's not necessarily well-defined.

Comment: If compiled using clang on arch the objects are densely packed in memory, when using g++ they are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Converting a variety of comments into a Community Wiki answer.*</sup>

- Are the assignments necessary? Does anything change if you use `V3(double a, double b, double c) : x(a), y(b), z(c) { cout << …; }`? (I don't expect there to be a difference.) Did you try printing the addresses of the class objects in `main()`? Does that throw any light on things? Ultimately, though, your question is futile — the compiler is allowed to use any layout and alignment it chooses as long as it gives the correct results.
- Just a guess: x86 cache lines are 64 bytes. By aligning this way, the first 2 objects would fit in 1 cache line, and the third would fit in a second cache line. If they were not aligned this way, the third object would be split across 2 cache lines which is bad. As already said though, it's not necessarily well-defined.
- If compiled using `clang` on arch the objects are densely packed in memory, when using `g++` they are not.